# java for loop implementation issue for some loop

Tags: java

I submitted my Java assignment for some program. My teacher commented that this code has some issues. I do not know what this mean? Any idea?

My submitted code looks like the following:

```
int FunctionOne(int a, int b) {
    for(int x = a; x >= 0; x--) {
        if (a % x == 0 && b % x == 0) {
            return x;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

**Note**: he gave me one program where he did not mention what it does and told me to fix the bug of those lines.

i also tried to figure out what it does. but i dont have any clue.

UPDATED: Original code which had bug looks like the following:

```
integer FunctionOne(int a  int b) {
    for(float x = a; x >= 0; x--) {
        if (a % x == 0 && b % x == 0) {
            return x;
            return x;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Given you haven't even said what it supposed to do, how do you expect a reasonable answer?

Comment: What is the code even supposed to do...?

Comment: he gave me one program where he did not mention what it does and told me to fix the bug of those lines.

Comment: @EliLopez No... `int method() { … }` is valid Java...

Comment: Wait!  You submitted this code, and you don’t know what it does?

Comment: it was the the code with bugs like wrong keyword spelling, statement closing etc. so, i fixed that and submitted

Comment: @blueMoon please show us the 'wrong' code the professor gave.

Comment: I added the wrong code

Answer (score 2):

Let's go through your code.

```
integer FunctionOne(int a  int b) {
```

What is `integer`? Change that to `int`.

Hold on... Where did the comma go? Put commas between arguments

```
    for(float x = a; x >= 0; x--) {
```

Why are you using floats? Use `int`. Also, once `x` reaches `0`, `% x` will cause a division by zero error, so do `; x > 0;`

```
        if (a % x == 0 && b % x == 0) {
            return x;
            return x;
```

Don't repeat the return statement...

```
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Final code should be:

```
int FunctionOne(int a, int b) {
    for(int x = a; x > 0; x--) {
        if (a % x == 0 && b % x == 0) {
            return x;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

(I'm assuming this is a `GCD` function)

If this is a GCD function, have this for future reference:

```
int GCD(int a, int b) {
    while (true) {
        if (b < a) {
            int t = a; a = b; b = t;
        }
        if (a == 0) return b;
        int t = a; a = b - a; b = a;
    }
}
```

It's faster (Euclid's algorithm).

Comment: @ your final code looks like mine which i asked. but he told me there are some issues. what it means? I just asked ...

Comment: Loop condition should be `x > 1`, since it will `return 1;` when the loop exits anyway.

Comment: @blueMoon This code avoids the possible division by zero error; yours did not.

Comment: @blueMoon No, this code doesn't look like yours, because question code has `x >= 0`, which will cause division by zero error, as this answer mentioned.

Comment: The code will of course only cause division by zero error if `a` is 0, otherwise the `if` statement will go true when `x = 1`, and return, so `x` will never reach 0.

Comment: @Andreas Even then it won't because it will break before the first execution of the `for`. `for(x;y;z)a;` is fancy for `x;while(y){a;z;}`. It's a while loop, not a do-while loop.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Sorry, I was unclear. I was referring to the question code, where `x >= 0` could potentially cause division by zero error, and is likely the "issue" the teacher was referring to, except it'll only happen if `a = 0`, otherwise the loop will return when `x` reaches 1.

Comment: @Andreas Oh yeah, that makes sense. Yes that's true. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
integer FunctionOne(int a  int b) {
for(float x = a; x >= 0; x--) {
    if (a % x == 0 && b % x == 0) {
        return x;
        return x;
    }
}
return 1;
}
```

Some points which I can think of:

> why you are returning the same value twice, return it only once.
>
> you are using float in for loop, you can use binary search instead, for loop is not meant for these kinds of things.

I will suggest that you use binary search.

If you want to know about binary search you can use this link.

https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/binary-search/a/binary-search

Comment: is this code block is the implementation of binary search?

Comment: No, it is not, you have to implement binary search yourself.  state your problem and check if it can be solved with binary search, using float in for loop is a bad idea, it will unnecessarily increase the time, moreover, I don't think it will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
int FunctionOne(int a, int b) {
    for(int x = a; x >= 0; x--) {
        if (a % x == 0 && b % x == 0) {
            return x;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Yes, there are some issues:

1. When X becomes 0 => throw ArithmeticException => must change to `for(int x = a; x > 0; x--)`
2. In best practive, you shold not return to many time in method. You should create a carried object for the result and then return in the end of method. => easy to maintance/ clearly code
3. Duplicated `return x`. How can you compile this source? No way!

Comment: #1 is only true if `a` is 0, otherwise loop will end when `x = 1`. --- I disagree with #2. Adding 3 more lines of code to prevent `return` from loop will not make code easier to maintain, and is certainly not clearer.

Comment: #1 is one possible test case and you must cover it. #2 how about if this is very big and conflex method? If you return everytime you got result, you can be got unexpected result or mistake when maintance. And the last, this method with bad algorithm.

Comment: #2 If the method is "very big and conflex" *(it isn't)*, and I *want* to return immediately, but instead set variable with return value, and another boolean variable to say I'm done, and somewhere later (out of view code, since it's so big) some code forgets to check boolean and does something unintended. The two pieces of code (the code wanting to exit, and the code doing something else) are far removed, so it's very **error prone**, i.e. **hard to maintain**, and it is certainly **not clear**, at the time to boolean is set, what remaining code will/should do.

Comment: ...cont'd... Of course, the answer is that code should never be that big, but that kind of defeats your argument.

Comment: @Andreas About #2, ok, I said `should not`, not `must`. For example in this case, use `break;` instead of `return` inside the `if` statement.